# Code diff using Roslyn CTP API

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm trying to do some basic code diff with the Roslyn API, and I'm running into some unexpected problems. Essentially, I have two pieces of code that are the same, except one line has been added. This should just return the line of the changed text, but for some reason, it's telling me that everything has changed. I have also tried just editing one line instead of adding a line, but I get the same result. I would like to be able to apply this to two versions of a source file to identify differences between the two. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
        SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(
            @"using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;

            namespace HelloWorld
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
                    }
                }
            }");

        var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.Root;

        var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                                     .AddReferences(
                                        new AssemblyFileReference(
                                            typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
                                     .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
        var nameInfo = model.GetSemanticInfo(root.Usings[0].Name);
        var systemSymbol = (NamespaceSymbol)nameInfo.Symbol;

        SyntaxTree tree2 = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(
            @"using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;

            namespace HelloWorld
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
                        Console.WriteLine(""jjfjjf"");
                    }
                }
            }");

        var root2 = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree2.Root;

        var compilation2 = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                                     .AddReferences(
                                        new AssemblyFileReference(
                                            typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
                                     .AddSyntaxTrees(tree2);

        var model2 = compilation2.GetSemanticModel(tree2);
        var nameInfo2 = model2.GetSemanticInfo(root2.Usings[0].Name);
        var systemSymbol2 = (NamespaceSymbol)nameInfo2.Symbol;

        foreach (TextSpan t in tree2.GetChangedSpans(tree))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tree2.Text.GetText(t));
        }
```

And here's the output I'm getting:

```
System
                using System
Collections
Generic
                using System
Linq
                using System
Text

                namespace HelloWorld
                {
                    class Program
                    {
                        static
Main
args
                        {
                            Console
WriteLine
"Hello, World!"
                            Console.WriteLine("jjfjjf");
                        }
                    }
                }
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Interestingly, it seems to show each line as tokens for every line except for the added line, where it displays the line without breaking it up. Does anyone know how to isolate the actual changes?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just looking for a simple [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) tool?

Comment: I was hoping to keep it within the Roslyn API because I'm using it to set up regression testing and I think it will be easier to keep the diff part in Roslyn's API. If this doesn't work though, I will probably end up using a tool like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx)

Comment: Are you interested in other tools that compute tree differences?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bruce Boughton's guess is correct. The GetChangedSpans method is not intended to be a general-purpose syntax diffing mechanism to take the difference between two syntax trees that have no shared history. Rather, it is intended to take two trees that have been produced by edits to a common tree, and determine which portions of the trees are different because of edits.

If you had taken your first parse tree and inserted the new statement into it as an edit, then you would see a far smaller set of changes.

It might help if I briefly describe how the Roslyn lexer and parser work, at a high level.

The basic idea is that lexer-produced "syntax tokens" and parser-produced "syntax trees" are *immutable*. They never change. Because they never change, we can re-use parts of previous parse trees in new parse trees. (Data structures which have this property are often called "persistent" data structures.)

Because we can re-use existing parts, we can, for example, use the same value for every instance of a given token, say `class`, that appears in the program. The length and content of every `class` token is exactly the same; the only things that distinguish two different `class` tokens are their *trivia*, (what spacing and comments surround them) and their *position*, and their *parent* -- what larger syntax node contains the token.

When you parse a block of text we generate syntax tokens and syntax trees in a peristent, immutable form, which we call the "green" form. We then wrap up the green nodes in a "red" layer. The green layer knows nothing about position, parents, and so on. The red layer does. (The whimsical names are due to the fact that when we first drew this data structure on a whiteboard, those are the colours that we used.)  When you create an edit to a given syntax tree, we look at the previous syntax tree, identify the nodes which changed, and then build new nodes *only on the spine of the changes*. All the other branches of the green tree stay the same.

When diffing two trees, basically what we do is *take the set difference of the green nodes*. If one of the trees was produced by editing the other, then *almost all the green nodes will be the same* because only the spine was rebuilt. The tree diffing algorithm will identify the changed nodes and work out the affected spans.

If the two trees have no history in common then the only green nodes they'll have in common are the individual tokens, which, as I said before, are re-used everywhere. Every higher-level green syntax node will be a different green node, and therefore be treated as different by the tree difference engine, even if its text is the same.

The *purpose* of this method is to allow the editor code to rapidly make a conservative guess about what portions of a text buffer need to be, say, recolourized, after an edit, or an undo, or some such thing. The assumption is that the trees have a historical relationship. The intention is not to provide a general-purpose textual difference mechanism; there are plenty of great tools for that already.

Imagine, for example, that you had pasted your first program into the editor, then highlighted the whole thing, then pasted the second program into the editor. One would reasonably expect that the editor would not waste time trying to figure out what portions of the pasted-down code happened to be identical with the previously-pasted code. That could be very expensive and the answer is likely to be "not much". Rather, the editor makes the conservative assumption that the entire pasted-over region is brand-new and entirely different code. It doesn't spend any time trying to make correspondences between the old code and the new code; it reparses and therefore recolourizes the whole thing.

If, on the other hand you had just pasted in the single different statement, then the editing engine would simply insert the edit into the right place. The parse tree would be regenerated *re-using the existing green nodes where possible*, and the difference engine would identify what spans need to be re-colourized: the ones with different green nodes.

Does that all make sense?

### UPDATE:

Ha, apparently Kevin and I were both typing out the same answer at the same time, in adjoining offices. A bit of duplicated effort, but I think both answers have good perspectives on the situation. :-)

Comment: That makes so much more sense. Thank you so much. I've been having trouble finding a lot of documentation for this kind of manipulation, so this was kind of a shot in the dark.

Comment: @user1059895: You're welcome. Obviously the documentation is nowhere near complete yet. Feel free to ask questions like this on the Roslyn forum as well.

Comment: Presumably, though, you could use the API to walk both syntax trees to perform a *semantic* diff on their structure. Yes? Are there any built-in utilities or APIs to help support semantic diffing?

Comment: @LBushkin: I would consider a *semantic* diff to be a diff that told you things like "in this version of the tree, this overload of Console.WriteLine was chosen but in that version, a different overload was chosen."  There is no easy way to get a summary of the semantic differences between two programs.  If what you want is a *syntactic* difference that ignores things like whitespace and is smart about things like re-ordering the classes in a file, then yes, it would be possible to build that pretty easily from the parts that Roslyn gives you.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks. What I'm interested in is, in fact, a semantic diff of the sort you describe.

Comment: @LBushkin: Roslyn will have a "speculative" semantic analyzer. That is, you can take an existing program and then say "hey, if I inserted a call to `M(x)` at this textual location in the program, which overload of M would be chosen and would there be any errors produced?"  Is that the sort of thing you need?

Comment: @Eric: No, not really. What I'd like to be able to do is to take two revisions of a program (more specifically a single method) and determine whether it has changes in a manner such that code that was previously reachable (some library methods somewhere, for instance) are no longer reachable, or vice versa. I already have a DGML callgraph - I just need to understand how a change to a method body would potentially change the executed code. I understand that there are complexities (polymorphism, delegates, lambdas, etc) but I don't need to worry about them in my initial case.

Comment: @LBushkin: Roslyn will have a flow analyzer that can answer questions like "is this statement reachable?" or "which local variables are not definitely assigned before they enter this region but are definitely assigned when control leaves the region?"  You could run the flow analyzer on both versions of your code and then compare the output.

Comment: @Eric: Ah ... brilliant! That sounds like exactly what I need. Now, when you say "will have" I presume it's not yet in the CTP?

Comment: @LBushkin: the methods are AnalyzeRegionControlFlow and AnalyzeRegionDataFlow, found on the ISemanticModel interface. They exist in the CTP release but I personally do not know how fully-featured they were when we did the release. Neither of those were my feature so I did not keep careful track of how far along they got before we released. If you want to give them a spin and send us feedback about whether they meet your needs or not, please do and leave a message on the forum with your opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

@bruceboughton is right, `GetChangedSpans` is intended to discover changes made by the incremental parser.  With code like the following, I get much better output:

```
        var code = 
        @"using System; 
        using System.Collections.Generic; 
        using System.Linq; 
        using System.Text; 

        namespace HelloWorld 
        { 
            class Program 
            { 
                static void Main(string[] args) 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!""); 
                } 
            } 
        }";
        var text = new StringText(code);
        SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(text);

        var index = code.IndexOf("}");
        var added = @"    Console.WriteLine(""jjfjjf""); 
                      ";

        var code2 = code.Substring(0, index) + 
                    added +
                    code.Substring(index);

        var text2 = new StringText(code2);

        var tree2 = tree.WithChange(text2, new [] { new TextChangeRange(new TextSpan(index, 0), added.Length) } );

        foreach (var span in tree2.GetChangedSpans(tree))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text2.GetText(span));
        }
```

However, in general GetChangedSpans is meant to be a reasonaby fast but conservative diff. For more control over the diff, and more accurate results, you probably want to implement your own tree-diffing algorithm that you can tune to meet your needs.

In the code above, if you are using VS, the editor has built in change reporting and text diffing that will allow you to easily construct the `TextChangeRange` objects, but otherwise you'll probably still need at least a text diffing algorithm if you want to be able to pass changes to the incremental parser.

Answer (score 6):

I would guess that `GetChangedSpans` is intended to compare changes between a tree and trees created from changes to the original tree, rather than between two arbitrary trees.